# How to make a CURL call to rasa nlu trainer

Tags: curl, meteor, rasa-nlu

I had rasa nlu trainer running on xxxx port.I want to feed nlu trainer with a different source  whenever a call made from my app(meteor) to rasa nlu trainer.I thought of curl request to nlu trainer but how can we fed --source flag of rasa nlu trainer with curl command?

or Do I have an another option to feed rasa nlu trainer with  a dynamic source path from my meteor application?
PLease direct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [As mentioned in their official documentation](https://nlu.rasa.ai/http.html), you can make cURL
>   Requests to RASA NLU using the **/train** endpoint. Its a HTTP POST
>   request, so make sure sending the corpus as request body.
>
> ```
> $ curl -XPOST localhost:5000/train?project=my_project -d @data/examples/rasa/demo-rasa.json
> ```

**Alternatively, you can do:**

Make a batch file having for training RASA like TrainRASA.bat which will have the following python command:

```
cd <Your Path>
python -m rasa_nlu.train -c config_spacy.json
```

Make the config_spacy.json file as follows:

```
{
    "project": "Travel",
    "pipeline": "spacy_sklearn",
    "language": "en",
    "num_threads": 1,
    "max_training_processes": 1,
    "path": "C:\\Users\\Kunal\\Desktop\\RASA\\models",
    "response_log": "C:\\Users\\Kunal\\Desktop\\RASA\\log",
    "config": "C:\\Users\\Kunal\\Desktop\\RASA\\config_spacy.json",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "port": 5000,
    "data": "C:\\Users\\Kunal\\Desktop\\RASA\\data\\FlightBotFinal.json",
    "emulate": "luis",
    "spacy_model_name": "en",
    "token": null,
    "cors_origins": ["*"],
    "aws_endpoint_url": null
  }
```

Now make a C# Web API to train your RASA Model like follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/TrainRASA")]
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public Task TrainRASA([FromUri] string BatchFilePath, [FromUri] string BatchFileDirectory)
{
            try
            {
             return Task.Run(() => 
              {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = BatchFilePath,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    WorkingDirectory = BatchFileDirectory
                };

                // Start the process with the info we specified.
                // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
                using (System.Diagnostics.Process exeProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
           });
         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
}
```

Now just make a HTTP GET from Chrome passing the batch file directory as arguments.

Comment: How about RASA Core Stack?

https://github.com/RasaHQ/starter-pack-rasa-stack

I would like to access my bot with curl command instead of using make cmdline.