# Failing to connect to localhost while using curl and rasa nlu

Tags: windows, curl, localhost, python-3.5, rasa-nlu

I have finally gotten to almost the very end of this `[rasa nlu tutorial][1]` and everything runs fine with the exception of me passing a new message to be scored:

I have tried this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5000/train?project=model_20180304-191830 -d demo-rasa.json
```

However, I get an error message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

I tried this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917529/how-to-make-a-curl-call-to-rasa-nlu-trainer) but to no avail. I thought it had something to do with my firewall, so I temporarily disabled it in case it was preventing it.

Comment: Needed to start the server first...

$ python -m rasa_nlu.server -c sample_configs/config_spacy.json

Comment: If the issue is resolved you can close the question.